# Execute multi update array Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a db table (form table for commercial propose) , the table is already filed with default rows, I want to execute multiple update query to change default values to the inserted values from from submit with post method in code igniter.. I have built a function `save_report()`.

I have tried to use `$this->db->update_batch();` , its only perform for the first foreach loop ..

```
function save_report(){

    $data['old_circle'] = $this->input->post('old_circle');
    $data['sold'] = $this->input->post('sold');
    $data['diffrent_come'] = $this->input->post('diffrent_come');
    $data['total'] = $this->input->post('total');
    $data['new_circle'] = $this->input->post('new_circle');
    $data['sold_start_month'] = $this->input->post('sold_start_month');
    $data['bought_start_month'] = $this->input->post('bought_start_month');
    $data['paid_start_month'] = $this->input->post('paid_start_month');

    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        $comp = array('sold_start_month','bought_start_month','paid_start_month');
        if(in_array($key,$comp)){
            $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>1,'name'     =>$key));
            $this->db->update('reports_det',array('value'=>$value));
        }
        $update_array[] = array(
            'name'        =>$key,
            'recived'     =>$value['recived'],
            'paid'        =>$value['paid'],
            'recived_bill'=>$value['recived_bill'],
            'paid_bill'   =>$value['paid_bill']
        );
        $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>1));
        $this->db->update_batch('reports_det',$update_array,'name');
    }
    redirect('c_panel/reports_det_mangment/1');

}
```

thanks a lot ..

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do here...You're using report_id = 1...which will only update one record...why would you use a loop  or batch_update to update one record? Secondly, you are using a "where" clause with update_batch, when the third param of update_batch is the "where."  Your code is REAL confusing...so unless you can make it more clear what you are trying to achieve...it's going to be hard to help out.

Comment: Also...you really shouldn't be doing db updates in your controller...you should probably have those in your Models...but that's another thing all-together.

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys for wasting your time ,  yesterday i was unfocused during work so today am really focus haha, the problem was i did not set foreach loop for every post array the final answer is here :

```
function save_report(){

    $report_id = $this->input->post('rid');
    if(count($_POST) > 0){

        $data['old_circle'] = $this->input->post('old_circle');
        $data['sold'] = $this->input->post('sold');
        $data['diffrent_come'] = $this->input->post('diffrent_come');
        $data['total'] = $this->input->post('total');
        $data['new_circle'] = $this->input->post('new_circle');
        $data['sold_start_month'] = $this->input->post('sold_start_month');
        $data['bought_start_month'] = $this->input->post('bought_start_month');
        $data['paid_start_month'] = $this->input->post('paid_start_month');


        foreach($data['old_circle'] as $key=>$value){
            $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>$report_id,'name'     =>'old_circle'));
            $this->db->update('reports_det',array($key=>$value));
        }
        foreach($data['sold'] as $key=>$value){
            $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>$report_id,'name'     =>'sold'));
            $this->db->update('reports_det',array($key=>$value));
        }
        foreach($data['diffrent_come'] as $key=>$value){
            $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>$report_id,'name'     =>'diffrent_come'));
            $this->db->update('reports_det',array($key=>$value));
        }
        foreach($data['total'] as $key=>$value){
            $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>$report_id,'name'     =>'total'));
            $this->db->update('reports_det',array($key=>$value));
        }
        foreach($data['new_circle'] as $key=>$value){
            $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>$report_id,'name'     =>'new_circle'));
            $this->db->update('reports_det',array($key=>$value));
        }
        foreach($data['sold_start_month'] as $value){
            $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>$report_id,'name'     =>'sold_start_month'));
            $this->db->update('reports_det',array('value'=>$value));
        }
        foreach($data['bought_start_month'] as $value){
            $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>$report_id,'name'     =>'bought_start_month'));
            $this->db->update('reports_det',array('value'=>$value));
        }
        foreach($data['paid_start_month'] as $value){
            $this->db->where(array('report_id'=>$report_id,'name'     =>'paid_start_month'));
            $this->db->update('reports_det',array('value'=>$value));
        }
    }
    redirect('c_panel/reports_det_mangment/'.$report_id);
}
```